# C++ Array of 120 objects with constructor + parameters, header- + sourcefile, no pointers please!

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, object, parameters

file.h:

```
extern objekt squares[120];
```

file.cpp:

```
objekt squares[120]= {objekt(objekt_size ,objekt_size ,-111,0)};
```

How can I init all objects at one time, all with the same parameters?

Comment: Is typing "please" really all that difficult? Edited.

Answer (score 9):

Don't use a raw array (because all the elements will be initialised via the default constructor).  Use e.g. a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<objekt> squares(120, objekt(objekt_size ,objekt_size ,-111,0));
```

Comment: Is this the only possibility? And what would be the pointer-solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) to repeat the same code 120 times.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum.hpp>

#define TO_BE_ENUMERATED(z, n, text) text

objekt squares[120] = {
    BOOST_PP_ENUM(120, TO_BE_ENUMERATED, objekt(objekt_size ,objekt_size ,-111,0))
};
#undef TO_BE_ENUMERATED
```